# Event is not rendering from $store.state Vuex

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, vuex, fullcalendar-5

I'm facing  problem to render my events on calendar, my Vuex is working fine (I think).
I can log my events in console.log and check in Vue DevTools.

Any advice to render on calender after I create in Vuex?
methods:

```
  methods: {
    handleDateClick(arg) {
      /* Get click event data */
      console.log(arg);
      /* Get event data in store */
      console.log(this.$store.state.events);
      this.$store.commit("addEvent", {
        id: new Date().getTime(),
        title: "Some event",
        start: arg.dateStr,
        allDay: arg.allDay,
      });
    },
  }
```

computed:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["events"]),
  }
```

Calendar component:

```
<Fullcalendar :options="calendarPlugins" :header="headerToolbar">
      <template #eventContent="{ timeText, event }">
        <b>{{ timeText }}</b>
        <i>{{ event.title }}</i>
      </template>
    </Fullcalendar>
```

Print of console and Vue DevTools: https://prnt.sc/2MzjMVmFSffT

I'm getting all data I need, but still not rendering on calendar...
Edit: full code https://github.com/lucaspmarra/fullcalendar-test

Comment: Hi Lucas, did you define the getter "events" in the store module? If so, could you provide the code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't see the full code example I can only guess, that you did not define a getter as followed:

```
events: (state) => state.events,
```

If you want to compute the state, change your code to

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["events"]),
  }
```

Hope I could help!

Comment: Sorry for that, Robin, you can check full project here: https://github.com/lucaspmarra/fullcalendar-test
I'll test what you told me!

Comment: Ok you defined the getter as I can See now. You need to delete the return statement in the mutation "addEvent", since it is for mutating a state, not for returning anything.

Comment: Still the same result, I removed the return and it still doesn't render the event in calendar.